# DataFrame Join in Pyspark to fetch the Records from both dataframes

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario where i want to join 2 dataframes, but none of the joins(left,right,inner,except) would serve my purpose.

Here are my Dataframe
Dataframe 1 :

### Date | Id | Owner | Id2 | Value|

20240101 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 100|

20240110 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 200|

Dataframe 2:

### Date | Id | Owner |

20240111 | 2 | 1 |

20240112 | 2 | 1 |

20240103 | 2 | 1 |

Output Dataframe :

### Date | Id | Owner | Id2 | Value|

20240101 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 100|

20240110 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 200|

20240111 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0|

20240112 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0|

20240103 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0|

Though the Dataframe1 had no values for some of the date but Dataframe2 had and hence the output should be containing the "Value" as 0

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **`Full`** join.

**`Example:`**

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('20240101',2,1,3,100),('20240110',2,1,3,200)],['date','id','owner','id2','value'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('20240111',2,1),('20240112',2,1),('20240113',2,1)],['date','id','owner'])
df2 = df2.toDF("date","id_2","owner_2")
df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b"),['date'],'full').withColumn("id", coalesce(df1['id'],df2['id_2'])).\
  withColumn("owner", coalesce(df1['owner'],df2['owner_2'])).\
    drop(*["id_2","owner_2"]).\
      fillna(0).\
        show()

#+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
#|    date| id|owner|id2|value|
#+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
#|20240101|  2|    1|  3|  100|
#|20240110|  2|    1|  3|  200|
#|20240111|  2|    1|  0|    0|
#|20240112|  2|    1|  0|    0|
#|20240113|  2|    1|  0|    0|
#+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
```